# iar ewarm linking to gcc eabi build library

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, calling-convention, iar

I have been able to build code in IAR EWARM (7.40) (for the ST STM32F407IG ARM Cortex-m4) which links to a library built under Ubuntu via gcc (4.9.3).  This *mostly* works but some build environment adjustments on either or both the IAR or gcc side still remain.  I would appreciate whatever help you can point me to.

There are no build errors evident but EWARM and arm-none-eabi-gcc disagree on the locations of parameters being passed to the gcc built library.  The EWARM debugger and the code generated by EWARM agree with each other but (it appears given investigations so far) that the locations expected by the gcc generated code are offset from those expected by EWARM by eight bytes.  I've only investigated a single call, so this may not be constant...

IAR's compiler flags include:  --aeabi and --guard_calls as per section: "AEABI compliance" in the EWARM help section.
arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler flags include: -gdwarf-3 -mabi=aapcs -march=armv7e-m -mthumb.

I believe this tells both EWARM and gcc to play nice together with ARM AAPCS standard procedure calls and dwarf v3 formats.

EWARM does seem to be happy with either -gdwarf-2 or -gdwarf-3 (but not -4).  This selection does not appear to affect the issue discussed above.

What else is required?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "What else is required?" appears to be nothing.  Just be darn sure that all of the macros evaluated by #ifdef statements match in the environments so you don't end up with different sized data structures in the two different environments!  #ifdef code is header files should be carefully evaluated...